# Mask/Clip an Image using a Polygon in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, kineticjs

Is it possible to mask/clip an `Image` using a `Polygon` in KineticJS?

**JSfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/LNeML/

In the jsfiddle, the Polygon should clip the Image of Yoda.

I did not see any clipping function in the docs for KineticJS objects. I was looking for a simple way to clip an Image, something similar to EaselJS:

```
star = new createjs.Shape(); 
star.graphics.beginStroke("#FF0").setStrokeStyle(5).drawPolyStar(0,0,50, 15,5,0.6).closePath();
bitmap.mask = star;
stage.addChild(bitmap);
```

Comment: How about using `polygon.setFill` and setting the fill with the image? http://jsfiddle.net/r8rtJ/1/

Comment: Whoa didnt know thats possible, yes it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, looking at your fiddle, I updated it: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/LNeML/409/)**

basically you need the newer version of kineticJS included in your project, this way you could do:

```
  fillPatternImage: ImageObject
```

as one of the polygon attributes. This fillPatternImage works for any shape and allows you to do what you want, but not in exactly the same way as EaselJS, I would say it is pretty easy though.