# complex clipping boundary in kinetic.js with draggable image

Tags: draggable, mask, kineticjs, clipping

Check out my html5 based clipping constraint on

http://shedlimited.debrucellc.com/test3/canvaskinclip.html

(messing with jsfiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/aqaP7/4/)

So, in html5 I can easily draw a shaped boundary like the following:

```
         context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(5, 5);
  context.lineTo(34, 202);

  context.lineTo(2, 405);
  context.lineTo(212, 385);
  context.lineTo(425, 405);
  context.lineTo(400, 202);
  context.lineTo(415, 10);
  context.lineTo(212, 25);
                context.clip();
```

In kinetic.js though, all I see for clipping options is: height, width, and x, y,

I came across the following : [Mask/Clip an Image using a Polygon in KineticJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014600/mask-clip-an-image-using-a-polygon-in-kineticjs), but the inner/fill image can't be set to draggable

any help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new kineticJS versions, a lot of the work is done in the background for you.

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-set-fill-with-kineticjs/):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hrjE/2/) gets you pretty close, here's the code:

```
 <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.0-beta2.js"></script>
    <script>
      function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        // get num of sources
        for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
        }
        for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
      }
      function draw(images) {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 600,
          height: 700
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        var patternPentagon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
          x: 220,
          y: stage.getHeight() / 4,
          sides: 5,
          radius: 70,
          fillPatternImage: images.yoda,
          fillPatternOffset: [-220, 70],
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 4,
          draggable: true
        });


        patternPentagon.on('dragmove', function() {
        //this.setFillPatternImage(images.yoda);
          //this.setFillPatternOffset(-100, 70);
          var userPos = stage.getUserPosition();
          this.setFillPatternOffset(-userPos.x,-userPos.y);
          layer.draw();
            this.setX(220);
            this.setY(stage.getHeight() / 4);
        });


        layer.add(patternPentagon);

        stage.add(layer);
      }
      var sources = {
        darthVader: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
        yoda: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg'
      };

      loadImages(sources, function(images) {
        draw(images);
      });

    </script>
  </body>
```

There is a more complex/accurate way of doing this without making it a background pattern, like with grouping objects together

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5hrjE/6/ update.  Basically, what you need to add to the 'group' is a some more shapes which would make the image not visible outside of the pentagon.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5hrjE/7/ an example of not such a good solution, but you get the idea. Again, you need to make the pentagon up front, and the image behind it. then you can set the dragmove on the pentagon to move the image instead of the pentagon like seen in http://jsfiddle.net/5hrjE/6/

Comment: I'll give it to you thx, out of laziness I ended up giving up on kinetic and sticking with an HTML5 source I found which allowed me to use my HTML5 border at http://shedlimited.debrucellc.com/test4/demo2.html   (although this sux because html5 has some issues etc)

Comment: thanks. KineticJS is pretty good, but for some reason, I cant figure out clipping regions for an image.